# How do I set text to textarea in formview in insert mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

DemHere is my textarea control:

```
<textarea id="Physical_DemandsTextBox" runat="server" cols="35" rows="6" value='<%# Bind("Physical_Demands") %>' />
```

Here is my logic that works with the other `asp:TextBox` controls

```
if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
   {
       TextBox txtPhyDem = FormView1.FindControl("Physical_DemandsTextBox") as TextBox;
   }

   if (txtPhyDem != null)
   {
         txtPhyDem.Text = "Failed Test of the Testing Testers.";
   }
```

When I run the application on insert mode the text area is blank. How do I fix this?

Comment: In which page event are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to replace textarea with textbox control as follow:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="Physical_DemandsTextBox" 
        TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="6" Columns="35" 
        runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("Physical_Demands") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Body` property, for sample:

```
if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
{
   Physical_DemandsTextBox.Body = "Failed Test of the Testing Testers.";
}
```

but you also could use directly the asp.net control what is better, for sample, in webform:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Physical_DemandsTextBox" runat="server" 
                                          TextMode="Multiline" 
                                          Columns="35" 
                                          Rows="6" />
```

and code behine:

```
if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
{
    Physical_DemandsTextBox.Text = "Failed Test of the Testing Testers.";
}
```